# How do I integrate this exponential function?

Tags: definite-integrals

$H = \frac{V^2}{R} e^{-2t/RC} dt$

From 0 to ∞.

I put $k = e^{-2t/RC}$

I tried taking log on both sides but got, something like
$log k - t/2k = -t/2RC$

How can I solve it

Comment: \begin{align*}
\int_0^M \frac{V^2}{R} e^{-2t/RC} dt&=\left.\frac{V^2}{R}\left(-\frac{RC}2e^{-\frac{2}{RC}t}\right)\right|_0^M
\end{align*}

Comment: \int_{a}^{b} = $\int_a^b$

Comment: @ÁngelMarioGallegos Thank you very much.

Comment: "Taking $\log$"? Definitely a bad idea. How about $\int_a^b e^t\,dt=e^b-e^a$ paired with a *correct use* of change of variables?

Comment: I forgot all maths after 1 month of my exam . So , silly of me. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\int_0^M \frac{V^2}{R} e^{-2t/RC} dt&=\left.\frac{V^2}{R}\left(-\frac{RC}2e^{-\frac{2}{RC}t}\right)\right|_0^M\\[3pt]
&=\frac{V^2C}{2}\left(1-e^{-\frac{2}{RC}t}\right)
\end{align*}
So
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{V^2}{R} e^{-2t/RC} dt&=\frac{V^2C}{2}\lim_{M\to\infty}\left(1-e^{-\frac{2}{RC}M}\right)\\[3pt]
&=\frac{1}{2}CV^2
\end{align*}